# Выбор случайного значения в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В общем есть база вида id | group | user

Надо выбрать 1 случайную строку из 100 которая содержит `group = "vip"` , а `user = ""`. И записать в user этой строки например `'что-то'`. Как это сделать?

UPD: Запрос в ответе не работает, выдает ошибку 1064, вот таблица, может что-то там поправить (ошибка у key).
[image: Таблица]

[image: Структура]

Comment: Ошибка при запросе, посмотрите 1 сообщение: что не так?

Comment: Вам дали верный ответ на оригинальный вопрос. Теперь на основе этого ответа вы написали какой-то свой код и он приводит к ошибке на ваших данных. В таком случае стоит задать новый вопрос. Приведите в нем фрагмент запроса и структуру БД. (А правку в старом вопросе просто никто не замечает, да и не нужно в одном вопросе последовательно задавать несколько).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант, это извлечь случайный идентификатор из этих таблиц

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  group = "vip" AND user = ""
ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
```

Далее полученный таким образом идентификатор использовать для UPDATE-запроса

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  user = 'что-то'
WHERE
  id = 3432
```

Будьте осторожны с ORDER BY RAND() на гигантских таблицах, так как это полный скан таблицы. Если есть возможность вычислить случайный идентификатор другим способом - хорошо бы им воспользоваться (однако, для этого нужно больше информации о проекте).

Comment: Кстати, `update tbl set user='что-то' where group = "vip" AND user = "" order by rand() limit 1` так же отлично сработает.

Comment: Ага, но с order by rand() нужно быть супер-осторожным, особенно, в MySQL, которая любит все вывалить на диск и сортировать там. Я обычно стараюсь всеми правдами и не правдами найти случайный идентификатор, особенно, если он проиндексирован, а индекс перегнали в память. В общем если таблица маленькая ORDER BY RAND() - самое милое дело, если большая - нужно уже как-то крутиться.

Comment: Ну это понятно и это вы в ответе уже отразили. с подобным order by любая СУБД свихнутся должна. вряд ли в каком то оптимизаторе специально предусмотрели такой случай